# Get current datetime using PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I want to add content to a MySQL table with current date and time.
When I insert the content to database it shows the correct date but the wrong time.

```
$date1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: It's inserting the server time not your local time.

Comment: Your PHP code and your MySQL server probably use different timezones.

Comment: how can i add my system time?..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 

$date1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

> Asia/calcutta has changed to Asia/Kolkata

Answer (score 4):

[a] strftime(): Format a local time/date according to locale settings

[b] date : Format a local time/date

Examples

Consider following simple example:

```
<?php
print strftime('%c');
?>
```

Output:

```
Mon Apr 23 01:22:58 2007
```

You need to pass format such as %c to strftime() to print date and time representation for the current system. You can use following format characters:

%m - month as a decimal number (range 01 to 12)
%d - day of the month as a decimal number (range 01 to 31)
%Y - year as a decimal number including the century
You can see the complete format conversion specifiers online here
You can also use date() as follows:

```
<?php
 print date('r');
 print "\\n";
 print date('D, d M Y H:i:s T');
 print "\\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
Mon, 23 Apr 2007 01:29:56 +0530
Mon, 23 Apr 2007 01:35:14 IST
```